# Regexp matching a string pattern the can contain all or part of a name in C#

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to replace all occurence of a lastname. However, the target strings contain ALL the letters of the lastname OR just a FEW characters of it. The target strings is never more than 30 characters long and is subdivided into 'sections' by character "/" (if this information will help)

For example, let's assume we have a last name = FLAHERTY that I am changing to PERRINS

I want to replace all strings for the name above in each string below, character for character. below is a before and after of the example.

MCDONN(3)/FLAH(3)CLAUSSEN    expected -> MCDONN(3)/PERR(3)CLAUSSEN

MCDONN(3)/FLAHER(3)/CLAUS  expected -> MCDONN(3)/PERRIN(3)/CLAUS

AB/BARAN/SHOOK(ATL)/FLAHERT(SM   expected -> AB/BARAN/SHOOK(ATL)/PERRINS(SM

STELL/RUBIN/(STELL/CLAUS/FLAH) expected -> STELL/RUBIN/(STELL/CLAUS/PERR)

Comment: Please tell in what environment you work. Text editor? Programming language? Which one?

Comment: I don't think this is a job for Regex's, because you would need to generate a different Regex for each use case.  You can't simply do something like (\w{3,10}) because it's going to match any word characters.  You need to be more specific in that you're looking for a specific subset of characters.  This might be more appropriate to tackle with code.

Comment: What is the minimum number of letters that must match in order for us to consider it a match? Is "Ab" considered to match "Abrahamson"?

Answer (score 1):

That would be one JavaScript-based solution:

```
var str  = "MCDONN(3)/FLAH(3)CLAUSSEN";
var find = /\bFLA(H(E(R(T(Y?)?)?)?)?)?\b/g; // assuming first 3 chars are req'd
var repl = "PERRINS";

var str2 = str.replace(find, function(match) {
  return repl.substr(0, match.length);
});
// -> "MCDONN(3)/PERR(3)CLAUSSEN"
```

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that it would also replace "FLARY". I don't think the OP wanted that. You could fix that by using `/\bFL(A(H(E(R(T(Y?)?)?)?)?)?\b/g`

Comment: @LarsH: Right, that's true. I'll change the regex. Thanks!